# Adicionar o percentual calculado no código em cima de cada barra do gráfico

Tags: python-3.x, gráfico, matplotlib

Gostaria de adicionar cada porcentagem calculada em cima de cada barra do gráfico e que cada barra fosse de uma cor diferente. O que modificar no meu código?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter

responses = [1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 5]

# creating the dataset
data = Counter(responses)

total = sum(data.values())#soma das frequencias

percentual = list(map(lambda x:x*100/total,data.values()))
notas = list(data.keys())

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))

# creating the bar plot
plt.bar(notas, percentual, color ='maroon',
        width = 0.4)

plt.xlabel("Notas atribuídas")
plt.ylabel("Percentual de cada nota")
plt.title("Pesquisa com alunos")
plt.show()
```

O código acima produz o gráfico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Para mudar a cor de cada barra do gráfico é necessário utilizar a seguinte construção no plt.bar(valores em RGB) :

```
plt.bar(notas, percentual, color = ['#000000','#AAAAAA','#FF0000'],
        width = 0.4)
```

Agora para adicionar as porcentagens em cima de cada barra, é necessário criar um loop "enumarate" com a função "plt.text". Segue um exemplo:

```
for i, x enumerate(percentual)
   plt.text(i, x, f'{x}', ha='center',fontsize=' ')
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).